# Align grid with ticks

Tags: r, plot, gridlines

When I let [`plot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.html) draw the axis, [`grid`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/grid.html) aligns with `ticks` [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8081931/850781).

However, my plot is somewhat involved:

```
mytime <- as.POSIXct("2015-08-20") + seq(0,by=3600,length.out=7*24)
plot(x=mytime,y=rnorm(7*24),xaxt="n")
ticks <- mytime[seq(1,by=12,to=length(mytime))]
axis(1, ticks, strftime(ticks, "%a %H:%M"))
grid(ny=NULL,nx=14)
```

and I cannot get the `grid` to align with the `ticks`:

[image: grid and ticks do not align]

How do I make them align?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [`abline`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html) is the answer:

```
mytime <- as.POSIXct("2015-08-20") + seq(0,by=3600,length.out=7*24)
plot(x=mytime,y=rnorm(7*24),xaxt="n")
ticks <- c(mytime[seq(1,by=12,to=length(mytime))],mytime[1]+7*24*3600)
axis(1, ticks, strftime(ticks, "%a %H:%M"))
grid(ny=NULL,nx=NA)
abline(v=ticks[seq(1,length(ticks),2)],lty="dotted",col="lightgray")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in the previous answer, the solution is using the `abline` function and avoid that the vertical guidelines are plotted in wrong locations. You can achieve both things by replacing the last line of your code

```
grid(ny=NULL,nx=14)
```

by

```
grid(ny=NULL,nx=NA)
abline(v = ticks, lty = 3, col = "lightgray")
```

to obtain

[image]

By the way, there are previous questions related to this that could have helped you:

1. [R: Finding the location of tick marks when plotting dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201759/r-finding-the-location-of-tick-marks-when-plotting-dates)
2. [Align grid() to plot ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010161/align-grid-to-plot-ticks)